# Finding an angle of triangle with inner circle

Tags: geometry

How to solve this problem:

[image]

I've found information that each angle of the triangle when lines are drawn from each vertex to the center of the circle will equally divide the angle of the inner vertex.

So it would possibly be $90^0$:

[image]

I also found that

$$\angle BIA = 90^0 + \frac 12 \angle BAC$$

which also leads me to $90^0$. Is this correct? But it seems that the angle is a bit smaller.

Comment: The drawing is a help, it has no reason to be exactly correct.

Comment: Use `\angle` to produce $\angle$. Or `\measuredangle` for $\measuredangle$.

Comment: @Flagged great! I forgot that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the tangent point on $BC$ be $T$. So $\angle ITB =\angle ITC = 90^\circ$.

$$\begin{aligned}
\angle BIC &= \angle BIT +\angle CIT\\
&=(90^\circ - \angle IBT) + (90^\circ - \angle ICT)\\
&=180^\circ - \frac12\angle ABC - \frac12\angle ACB\\
&= 180^\circ - \frac12(180^\circ- \angle BAC)\\
&= 90 + \frac12\angle BAC
\end{aligned}$$

Since $\angle BIC = 135^\circ$, $\angle BAC = 90^\circ$.

Answer (score 1):

Simply
$$\angle BAC= \pi-2y-2\alpha$$